# Underscore equivalent of _.pick for arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I understand that pick is used to get back an object with only specified properties:

```
_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'name', 'age');
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}
```

How would I perform that same operation on an array, say I have an array such as:

```
[{name: 'moe1', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'},
{name: 'moe2', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'},
{name: 'moe3', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}]
```

and I want to map it to an array so to include only the `name` and `age` properties, like:

```
[{name: 'moe1', age: 50},
{name: 'moe2', age: 50},
{name: 'moe3', age: 50}]
```

Do I have to do an `each()` on the array then perform a `pick()` on each object, or is there a cleaner way?

**EDIT**

Sorry but just another small requirement, how would I perform a where (i.e. get all those whose age is greater than 50) and then perform the `pick`?
**EDIT**
got it done like this, was unaware of how chaining works in underscore.

```
_(data).reject(function (r) { return d.age<51; }).map(function (o) {
            return _.pick(o, "age", "name");
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to use `_.map` and apply the same `_.pick` on all the objects.

```
var data = [{name: 'moe1', age: 30, userid: 'moe1'},
            {name: 'moe2', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'},
            {name: 'moe3', age: 60, userid: 'moe1'}];

var result = _.map(data, function(currentObject) {
    return _.pick(currentObject, "name", "age");
});

console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ { name: 'moe1', age: 50 },
  { name: 'moe2', age: 50 },
  { name: 'moe3', age: 50 } ]
```

If you want to get the objects in which the age is > 50, you might want to do, like this

```
var data = [{name: 'moe1', age: 30, userid: 'moe1'},
            {name: 'moe2', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'},
            {name: 'moe3', age: 60, userid: 'moe1'}];

function filterByAge(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.age && currentObject.age > 50;
}

function omitUserId(currentObject) {
    return _.omit(currentObject, "userid");
}

var result = _.map(_.filter(data, filterByAge), omitUserId);    
console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ { name: 'moe3', age: 60 } ]
```

You can do the same with chaining, [as suggested by rightfold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280775/underscore-equivalent-of-pick-for-arrays/22280789?noredirect=1#comment33847612_22280789), like this

```
var result = _.chain(data).filter(filterByAge).map(omitUserId).value();
```

Comment: Seems weird that you have to do a `map` first. Seems like something Underscore would have a function for. Considering `pluck` does this exact things except on a single field.

Answer (score 1):

You can take just one lodash method for that (~50kb import):

```
npm i lodash.pick
```

Solution:

```
const pick = require('lodash.pick')

const filterValues = ['name', 'age']
const arr = [
    { name: 'moe1', age: 52, userid: 'moe1' },
    { name: 'moe2', age: 50, userid: 'moe1' },
    { name: 'moe3', age: 50, userid: 'moe1' }
]

const result = arr
    .filter(item => item.age < 51)
    .map(item => pick(item, filterValues))
```

Output:

```
[ { name: 'moe2', age: 50 }, { name: 'moe3', age: 50 } ]
```